# Can Redshift Spectrum handle trailing space after a field enclosed in double quotes while reading csv file?

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift, external-tables, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a csv file which has fields enclosed in double quotes. I created an Redshift external table over it using OpenCSVSerDe. 
The issue is one of my rows in the file has a trailing space outside the double quotes. Something like this:

```
"name1" ,"123","something"
"name2","234","somethingelse"
```

Now a SELECT on the external table returning NULL in the first row for the first column.

```
       123  something
name2  234  somethingelse
```

However, the S3 SELECT functionality is returning proper values as below:

```
name1  123  something
name2  234  somethingelse
```

Is there any property at the table level which i can use to properly retrieve the data or this is a limitation?

Table DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_table
(
 column1 varchar(50)
,column2 varchar(50)
,column3 varchar(100)
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('separatorChar' = ',') --checked with and without this
STORED AS textfile
LOCATION 's3://s3bucketlocation'
;
```

Comment: Is it being caused by the space before the comma in the first row? Can you edit your question to show the `CREATE TABLE` command you used, so that we can try to recreate the situation?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, it's the space after "name1".. Also added the DDL in the question

Comment: Is it just happening on that first line, or are there many lines with the "space-comma" problem? Any chance you could simply clean-up the file before loading it?

Comment: Yeah, pre-processing is always an option but here i wanted to know if there are any Spectrum capabilities which can handle spaces like this. Obviously this space is due to a manual/data error and is not a correct format but since S3-Select handles it, I thought may be Spectrum can also handle it.

Comment: Just so that you know, I already corrected it in the upstream (was just in the 1st line) but we should always keep finding different solutions to a single problem, so still exploring :)